# Distinction between with/by means of

Tags: differences, prepositions

Consider the following examples:

1. Data are usually input *by means of* a keyboard or scanner.
2. The variation of the distance was measured *with* a magnetic position detector.
3. We can change this value *by means of* the up and down arrow on the keyboard.
4. To move the visible region without resizing it, drag it *with* the cursor.

Under what condition is *with* used instead of *by means of*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[by means of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/by+means+of) is defined as: with the use of; owing to:

> They succeeded by means of patience and sacrifice.

*with* is a preposition, one meaning of which is *(of means or instrument) by the use of; using: to cut with a knife.

I think that any time you can substitute *with the use of* for *by means of*, you can use *with*.